# Select dynamically created checkbox if another dynamically created checkbox is selected

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to select checkboxes (created dynamically) if another checkbox (also dynamically created) is checked?

What I want to do is to group checkboxes based on their names.

For example: `'create family', 'edit family', 'delete family'`
would be grouped by the string `family`.

Then, create the checkboxes using these strings, and add event listeners between them, so if a `parent` is selected, the others are selected too.

For example: if `family` is selected, `'create family', 'edit family', 'delete family'` should be selected

Here's what I'm doing:

```
public void fillPermisions() {
    System.out.println("filling up the permissions");
    Call<List<Permission>> permCall = retro.getPermissionList();
    permCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Permission>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Permission>> call, Response<List<Permission>> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    permList =  response.body();
                    numPermissions = permList.size();
                    HBox hbox = null;
                    VBox vbox = null;
                    CheckBox parent = null;
                    String xx = "";

                    /*
                    Here, permList is a list like this:
                    ['create family', 'edit family', 'delete family', 'create users', 'edit users', ...]
                    So, I'm grouping these by the second string.
                    */

                    for(int i=0; i<numPermissions; i++){
                        String[] parts = permList.get(i).getName().split(" ");

                        if (!xx.equals(parts[1])) {
                            xx = parts[1];

                            if (i!=0) {
                                vBoxPermissions.getChildren().add(hbox);
                            }

                            hbox = new HBox();
                            vbox = new VBox();

                            System.out.println(xx);
                            parent = new CheckBox();
                            parent.setMinWidth(200);
                            parent.setText(xx);

                            /* HERE! if parent is checked, check all the others generated dynamically */

                            hbox.getChildren().add(parent);

                            CheckBox cbPerm = new CheckBox();
                            cbPerm.setMinWidth(20);
                            cbPerm.setText(permList.get(i).getName());
                            cbPerm.setUserData(permList.get(i));
                            vbox.getChildren().add(cbPerm);
                            hbox.getChildren().add(vbox);


                        } else {
                            CheckBox cbPerm = new CheckBox();
                            cbPerm.setMinWidth(20);
                            cbPerm.setText(permList.get(i).getName());
                            cbPerm.setUserData(permList.get(i));
                            vbox.getChildren().add(cbPerm);
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Permission>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Error fill table Role");
        }
    });

}
```

And here's what I want to do:
basically select the checkboxes at the right if the left checkbox is selected.

[image: Dinamically created checkboxes]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding all the child checkboxes to an `HBox`, you could add a `ForEach` loop to the listener on the `parent` checkbox:

```
for (Node cb :
    hbox.getChildren()) {
    ((CheckBox)cb).setSelected(true);
}
```

This will go through every node in the `HBox`, cast it to a `CheckBox` and select it.

If you want all the checkboxes to be toggled selected/unselected based on the `selectedProperty` of the `parent`, you have two options.

One is to use the same loop as above, but call `setSelected()` based on the parent's selected status:

```
parent.selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
    for (Node cb :
        hbox.getChildren()) {
        ((CheckBox)cb).setSelected(isSelected);
    }
});
```

The other option is to bind the new checkbox's value to that of the parent. This doesn't require a loop:

```
cbPerm.selectedProperty().bind(parent.selectedProperty());
```

Which method you choose depends on how the rest of your application is structured; the code you provided doesn't quite provide enough details, but this should get you heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to get a `Map<String, List<Permission>>`. This allows you to easily create the corresponding `CheckBox`es for the group and the sub elements in the same iteration of a loop by iterating the entry set.

Create a `List` of the sub `CheckBox`es in the group to allow you to update them when you change the selected state of the group `CheckBox` and check, if all, none or some `CheckBox`es are selected to update the group `CheckBox`.

To properly align all `CheckBox`es independent of the length of the group names I recommend using a `GridPane` btw.

You need to adjust this a bit to accomodate for the fact that your list contains `Permission`s:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    List<String> permList = Arrays.asList("1 a", "2 a", "3 a", "1 b", "2 b", "3 b");

    // group strings by second word
    Map<String, List<String>> groups = permList.stream()
                                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split(" ")[1],
                                                                              LinkedHashMap::new,
                                                                              Collectors.toList()));

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(20);

    int index = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : groups.entrySet()) {
        // create CheckBox for group
        CheckBox groupBox = new CheckBox(entry.getKey());
        grid.add(groupBox, 0, index);

        List<String> value = entry.getValue();

        // list of CheckBoxes for sub elements of group
        List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>(value.size());

        // select/unselect CheckBoxes from group when group box is selected/unselected
        groupBox.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            for (CheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
                cb.setSelected(newValue);
            }
        });

        // create sub CheckBoxes
        for (String s : value) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(s);
            cb.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                // update group CheckBox to unselected, selected or indeterminate
                // respectively if all, none or some CheckBoxes are selected.
                long count = checkBoxes.stream().filter(CheckBox::isSelected).count();
                groupBox.setIndeterminate(false);
                if (count == 0) {
                    groupBox.setSelected(false);
                } else if (count == checkBoxes.size()) {
                    groupBox.setSelected(true);
                } else {
                    groupBox.setIndeterminate(true);
                }
            });
            checkBoxes.add(cb);
            grid.add(cb, 1, index++);
        }
    }

    final Scene scene = new Scene(grid);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

With the above implementation you not only update the sub `CheckBox`es, you also set the state of the group `CheckBox` according to the number of selected `CheckBox`es in the group:

- unselected, if no `CheckBox`es are selected
- selected, if all `CheckBox`es are selected
- indeterminate otherwise